# How to print pdf file from document file with korean language in apache poi. I tried using the pdfOptions.fontEncoding("UTF-8")

Tags: java, itext, apache-poi

How to print pdf file from document file with korean language in apache poi. I tried using the pdfOptions.fontEncoding("UTF-8")

```
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath + fileName);
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath + fileWithoutExtension + ".pdf");
            XWPFDocument xwpfDocument = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);

            // Convert document to pdf
            PdfOptions pdfOptions = PdfOptions.create();
            `pdfOption set for font encoding`
            pdfOptions.fontEncoding("UTF-8");
            
            `Convert to pdf`
            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(xwpfDocument, outputStream, pdfOptions);
```

Comment: In Java Code , the part `pdfOption set for font encoding` cannot be compiled. Have you done some real code by yourself?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.